# Get-childitem is not working with foreach loop

Tags: powershell, automation, powershell-4.0

Trying to delete files from multiple path,

So have created a csv file like path,days,filter

importing this file in shell and looping over each object to delete contents, but getchilditem is failing again and again,
Unable to understand reason behind that,

Below is the code what m trying to achieve

```
Start-Transcript -Path "D:\delete.log"

$pathlist= Import-csv -LiteralPath "D:\diskpath.csv"
$count = 0

foreach($p in $pathlist){

    Write-host $p.path " | " $p.days -ForegroundColor DarkCyan
    $path = $p.path
    $days = $p.days
    $filter = $p.filter

    Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Filter $filter | where-object{$_.LastWriteTime -lt [datetime]::Now.AddDays(-$days)}|Remove-Item -Force -Verbose -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Confirm $false
    
}


Stop-Transcript
```

without for loop, script executes properly, but with for loop it fails

Please let know if any further information needed on this query,
will like provide the same,
have already google and read multiple questions here at SO, but unable to find reason behind failure,

Comment: What do you mean by "it fails"? No files are deleted? Wrong files are deleted? An error message?

Comment: As aside, the default value for `Confirm` is False, so you can either leave that out or use the correct syntax for it: `-Confirm:$false`. Also, show us the **text** for the first 3 or 4 lines of your `D:\diskpath.csv` file, so we can see if anything is wrong there.

Comment: `-Confirm` is a switch parameter and it defaults to `$false` in this case. If you want to provide a variable to a switch don't use space but a `:` > `-Confirm:$false` / `-Confirm:$VarWithBool`. If you leav a space the switch parameter is seen as `$true` and the next positioned parameter gets the `$false`...

Comment: @vonPryz fails, means it is not deleting any files, neither showing anything on verbose, but same if share path is provided in variable and passed without for loop it works

Answer (score 0):

@T-Me and @Theo

Thanks for highlighting error, haven't looked type error in script my bad, whereas while manual typing in PowerShell was writing correctly, but in script made mistake, now its working-

```
Start-Transcript -Path "D:\delete.log"

$pathlist= Import-csv -LiteralPath "D:\diskpath.csv"
$count = 0

foreach($p in $pathlist){

    Write-host $p.path " | " $p.days -ForegroundColor DarkCyan
    $path = $p.path
    $days = $p.days
    $filter = $p.filter

    Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Filter $filter | where-object{$_.LastWriteTime -lt [datetime]::Now.AddDays(-$days)}|Remove-Item -Force -Verbose -Recurse
    
}
```